# ignore_row_on_dupkey_index not working with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-data, oracle-sqldeveloper, spring-jdbc

I am trying to run schema.sql and data.sql file as per below code in spring boot application. However, it's still failing with unique constraint violation exception.

**Is there any other way with which I can avoid unique contraint violation ?
or how to resolve this one?**

```
@Configuration
public class DataInitializerConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Datasource")
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
        Resource initSchema = new ClassPathResource("schema.sql");
        Resource initData = new ClassPathResource("data.sql");
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(initSchema, initData);
        databasePopulator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(true);
        databasePopulator.setSeparator("**END OF FILE**");
        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
}
```

schema.sql and data.sql script seems to be fine as I can see no error while running here [fiddele](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f03fe)

data.sql as below:

```
DECLARE id varchar(20);

BEGIN

select dbms_random.string('x',10) into id from dual;

INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(TABLE1, PK_A) */ INTO TABLE1 (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K)
select
     id ,
     dbms_random.string('x',255) ,
     dbms_random.string('x',255) ,
     dbms_random.string('x',10) ,
     dbms_random.string('x',5) ,
     sysdate + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400 * 30 ,
     sysdate + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400 * 30 ,
     sysdate + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400 * 30 ,
     dbms_random.string('x',50),
     decode(round(dbms_random.value), 1, 'Y', 'N'),
     decode(round(dbms_random.value), 1, 'Y', 'N')
     FROM DUAL

connect by level <=10;

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (A,L,M,N)
select
     id ,
     trunc(dbms_random.value(0.01, 9999.99),2) ,
     sysdate + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400 * 30 ,
     decode(round(dbms_random.value), 1, 'Y', 'N')
     FROM DUAL

connect by level <=10;

END;
**END OF FILE**
```

schema.sql as below :

```
begin
  for rec in (select table_name
              from   all_tables
              where  table_name IN ('TABLE1','TABLE2')
             )
  loop
    execute immediate 'drop table '||rec.table_name;
  end loop;
  
    Execute Immediate 'CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (A VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, B VARCHAR(255), C VARCHAR(255),
D VARCHAR(10), E VARCHAR(5), F TIMESTAMP, G TIMESTAMP, H TIMESTAMP,
I VARCHAR(50), J VARCHAR(1), K VARCHAR(1),CONSTRAINT PK_A PRIMARY KEY (A))';

  Execute Immediate 'CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (A VARCHAR(10), L DECIMAL, M TIMESTAMP, N VARCHAR(1))';

end;

**END OF FILE**
```